# how can I plot a function which takes 2 arguments in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written this code. I am trying to plot the specified vector x against a specified response variable y.

```
projection <- function(x,k) {
  delta <- (max(x)-min(x))/(k-2)
  n <- length(x)
  t <- seq(from = min(x)-2*delta, 
           to = max(x)-delta, 
           length.out = k)
  Z <- matrix(NA, 
              nrow = n, 
              ncol = k)
 for (i in 1:nrow(Z)) {
   for (j in 1:ncol(Z)) {
     Z[i,j] <- bspline(x[i] - t[j], delta=delta)
   }
 }
  # P = Zx(Z⊤Z)^−1xZ⊤
  Zt <- t(Z)
  ZtZ <- crossprod(Z)
  Ztz.inv <- solve(ZtZ)
   P <- Z%*%Ztz.inv%*%Zt
   out <- list(x,delta,Z,P)
  return(out)
  
}

projection(2:6,4)

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(seq(-1, 4, length.out=250))), aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=projection) +
  labs(y= "Py", x = "x")
```

I get the following warning:
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_function()`:
argument "k" is missing, with no default

where am I suppose to put k in order to plot my function

Comment: try this stat_function(fun=projection, k=4)

Comment: @user12256545

for some reason its still giving the same warning

Answer (score 0):

In `stat_function` you can specify additional arguments to `fun` using the `args` argument.  I don't know where the `bspline` function came from, so I can't demonstrate with your code, but here's something similar:

```r
projection <- function(x,k) {
  x^k
}

projection(2:6,4)
#> [1]   16   81  256  625 1296

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(seq(-1, 4, length.out=250))), aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=projection, args = list(k = 4)) +
  labs(y= "Py", x = "x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>